# Bootstrap navbar span inside li class active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't know what is the purpose of span in bootstrap original navbar ? 
when I delete it nothing happen.
Can anyone tell please?

```
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The span has a class of **sr-only** that is used only for screen readers to present better information. It's make a better **Web accessibility**. For example if you use **JAWS Screen Reader** and get to the span with **sr-only** it will read loudly which text is inside the element.

This helps people with temporary or permanent disabilities to better understand content on your site, so it is good to leave it and not remove.